# What this Error Means "Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Hi Every one I just want to ask what kind of Error is This, I can't find Best Solution on Google

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I Try Both OLEDB and ODBC Connection, But this error happen on ODBC
[image]

Upon Test the connection it Succeeded
[image]

But when I run it , Error message above appear.

By the way I used iSeries Access ODBC Driver
[image]

Do you have Suggestion ?

Comment: "There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure." Look around, there's likely something else that fired an Error event. As the connection seems to work with OLE but not ODBC, is there a particular reason you need ODBC to work?

Comment: from sample above, when I run OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination it succeed but when I tried to run ODBC Source to OLE DB Destination it failed,  ODBC to OLE DB is important for me because all raw data stored from ODBC and transform this raw data into our Database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I tried several things, in my case the ODBC component worked for some tables, and for others it failed even more strangely, the only solution was to approve everything to run in 32 bits.

[Run64BitRuntime False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K8Vd.png)

I hope you solve your problem